# How can I convert hiragana to half-width katakana?

Tags: java, android, unicode, localization, cjk

I want to convert hiragana characters to half-width katakana characters. How can I do this on Android?

I have code to convert Hiragana to Katakana as below...

```
 private char hiraganaTokatakana(String hiraganastring) {

    char hiraganachar = Character.valueOf(hiraganastring.charAt(0));
    // convert char to unicode value
    String hiraganahex = Integer.toHexString(hiraganachar & 0xFFFF);
    // convert unicode to decimal
    int hiraganadecimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(hiraganahex, 16);
    // convert hiragana decimal to katakana decimal
    int katakanadecimalNumber = Integer.valueOf(hiraganadecimalNumber) + 96;
    // covert decimal to unicode value
    String katakanahex = Integer.toString(katakanadecimalNumber, 16);
    // convert unicode to char

    return (char) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(katakanahex), 16);
}
```

This Code Converts Hiragana to Katakana But also I want to Convert Hiragana to Half Width Katakana,how to do it ?

Comment: have you tried mapping to their unicode values? i dont think there is a method that does this directly, you might find a library if you goggle but you could just map them yourself. similar to parsing, get each hiragana and replace for its katakana.

Comment: please if you have code then please show the code.

Comment: Focus on describing your problem, what you've tried, etc. If people know the answer, they will tell you, even if you aren't desperate. On the other hand, some (many?) might attribute your desperation to poor planning and/or laziness on your part, and not try too hard to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is formalized in the Unicode standard, and [java.text.Normalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html) should be able to handle it. I have no idea how well it works on Android though. Here's Java SE tutorial: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html

Comment: What do you want? Did you try it? What results did you get?

Comment: You don't have to use a jar file, that class is part of the core Java API, available in Android. Did you even try it? Or read the tutorial?

Comment: I have code to convert Hiragana to Katakana as below...  Check edited Question.

Comment: This code is best a hack, and may not work for all characters. Converting to half-width may require normalization, which is not as simple as shifting Unicode values. So, either use `Normalizer` or build your own table.

Answer (score 0):

http://mariten.github.io/kanatools-java/en/kana-converter/ should work:

```
int conversion_flags = OP_ZEN_HIRA_TO_HAN_KATA;
String output = KanaConverter.convertKana(input, conversion_flags);
```